# Getting error while running gstreamer

Tags: embedded-linux

How to use gstreamer in qualcomm apq8053?

While running the pipeline getting this error:

> It isn't a v4l2 driver. Check if it is a v4l1 driver

Comment: The video driver you opened is incompatible with v4l2. You should look for an updated one. The error message is here: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-good/blob/master/sys/v4l2/v4l2_calls.c

Comment: yes i know that but what should i do to solve the error??there is mm-qcamera-daemon process which continuously using video0 node in /dev

Answer (score 1):

```c
/* Structure to contain all our information, so we can pass it to callbacks */
typedef struct _CustomData {
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstElement *source;
  GstElement *convert;
  GstElement *sink;
} CustomData;
```